# Filter Array data in angular with specific format

Tags: javascript, angular

How to filter Specific format type of data from Array, i only want data with [],like Name[Name],Type[Type],Status[Status]

```
{
    "column": [
        "Exam ID(id|Optional)",
        "Name[Name]",
        "Result Type",
        "Type[Type]",
        "Status[Status]"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "17",
            "test",
            "PUBLISH_LATER",
            "LEVEL",
            "ONGOING"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this.

```js
var x = { "column": [ "Exam ID(id|Optional)", "Name[Name]", "Result Type", "Type[Type]", "Status[Status]" ]}

var filterData = x.column.filter(v => {
  return /[a-zA-Z[a-zA-Z]]/g.test(v);
})

console.log(filterData);
```

Let me know if have doubt.

Comment: Suggestion: Before giving solution just check what approach he tried.